# Archive of iOS app says uploaded correctly to iTunes connect but can't be seen

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I've recently written my first iOS app in swift using Xcode and am trying to get it into iTunes connect. I have set up the app record with the same identifier as in Xcode, archived the app and uploaded (again with Xcode). The uploader result says that's it's been successful (with the green tick) but in the iTunes connect under activity there is no sign of it. This is after waiting overnight.

Has anyone else had this problem recently? Also my understanding was that if there were errors the uploader normally identifies these (such as no app record found). Is there anything else I should be doing or is this something apple should be resolving?

Comment: Sometimes it happens, do not panic use Application Loader.

Comment: Sometimes changing system to upload app also help.

Comment: While uploading archived make sure Xcode window is active and after uploading successful  check iTunes connect in activity section there are showing archive with your uploaded app version with waiting status or not, because it's take some time to change waiting status of archive, if there are no archive with your uploaded version means uploading not successful. You can also try App loader for best results.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and surprisingly I just had to wait. Unfortunately I can't tell you exactly how long to wait because I checked my build after a month and it was successfully uploaded to iTunes connect. Make sure to look into iTunes connect -> My Apps -> iOS App (App status) -> Build

It should look like this when it's done:

[image]

Comment: Sounds mad to wait a month! Imagine if that app was going to support salaries for a development team!

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to a missing permission in info.plist file, you will receive an email for this on the email id registered with the account, if this happens.

Please check the email id for such a mail. It will be described there which permission is not mentioned in the info.plist.

You can then fix this and re-upload the build. Also, ensure that you have changed the build/version number else you will get an error that build with same version/build number already has already been uploaded.

Comment: Hmmm not received any emails.

Answer (score 0):

So in case anyone else has this problem I 'solved' it by: 
Not using the downloaded application uploader but by running it from the Xcode > Developer menu within Xcode itself. It showed in the activity part of iTunes connect immediately.